# Iterate over google sheet/ excel column letters

Tags: python, pygsheets

Basically, I am trying to loop over spreadsheet column letters in python, but I have no clue what I am doing wrong. For context the -1 on the first call is because the first letter of the alphabet is 1, not 0. I get no end, and instead, it loops at rem = 22, and the letter q. The requirements I have are that the last letter ( BX**D**) not be divisible by three (what the triple portion of the code focuses on). If there is a better way to do this than recursion, then I'm all ears.

```
Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ"
def function(num):
    str = ""
    i = 0
    while num >= 1:
        if num > 26:
            rem = num % 26
            print("Rem ", rem)
            str = str + function(rem)
        else:
            triple = num % 3 
            if triple != 0 : 
                print(Alphabet[num])
                return Alphabet[num]
print(function(100-1))
```

Comment: are you using this in pygsheets ? if so, you can use tuple for addressing.

Comment: How? and yes. @Nithin

Answer (score 0):

All the pygsheets functions that take an Address will accept a label or tuple r Address object. please note that this does not have the triple logic you need.

```
for x in range(1, 100):
  value = wks.get_value((x, 1)) # first cell in each column
  print(value)
```

see [docs here](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.cell)

Comment: This is the greatest thing I have ever heard. Thank you! one quick question @nithin.  Whats the formatting on putting np arrays in a column? The documentation made it unclear. my array labels are x, and y. Also, I am trying to update value, so how would the string look?

Comment: you can put them as either list of lists and do update_values() or convert to dataframe and do set_df()